# Unable to create Polygone from GeoDjango Admin interface

Tags: django, gis, postgis, geodjango

I am new to GeoDjango. I have created Admin interface for my Model. It loads correctly. I am also able to draw the Polygone on map(At client side) but when I save It tells me Invalid input and throws some error in console.

**Model**

```
from django.contrib.gis import models


Poly(models.Model):
    poly_gon = models.Polygone()
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

**Admin interface**

```
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from myapp.models import Poly


admin.site.register(Poly)
```

**Error at Client side(On the polygon field in red colour)**

> "Invalid geometry value."

**Error at server side(in terminal, after starting server with runserver command)**

```
Error in server side: GEOS_ERROR: ParseException: Expected 'Z', 'M', 'ZM', 'EMPTY' or '(' but encountered : ')'

GEOS_ERROR: ParseException: Expected 'Z', 'M', 'ZM', 'EMPTY' or '(' but encountered : ')'

Error creating geometry from value 'SRID=4326;POLYGON()' (Error encountered checking Geometry returned from GEOS C function "GEOSWKTReader_read_r".)
```

I was able to enter data to my Poly from shell by following code.

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry
from myapp.models import Poly
p = Poly(poly_gon=GEOSGeometry("""POLYGON((-87.6705551147461 41.89135645852043, -87.64171600341797 41.89288988217029, -87.63690948486328 41.880110226947934, -87.66368865966797  41.87806524488436, -87.68016815185547 41.887267148816726, -87.6705551147461 41.89135645852043))"""))
p.save()
```

Comment: `POLYGON()` is invalid, so should fail. If you want an empty polygon, the correct WKT is `POLYGON EMPTY`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a GeoAdmin Admin with your model to create a Polygon.

```
admin.site.register(Poly, admin.GeoModelAdmin)
or
admin.site.register(Poly, admin.OSMGeoAdmin) # for openstreet map
```

> As described here:
>   https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138006/unable-to-create-polygon-using-geodjango-admin-interface